# Is it possible to fingerprint a file agnostic of it's type?

Tags: file, go

Is it possible to add a fingerprint to a file programmatically that works on every filetype? I'm trying to track down leaks and am wondering if doing something like the following to fingerprint any file completely agnostic of the type.

```
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

defer f.Close()

if _, err = f.WriteString(text); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to checksum the files?

Comment: You can checksum any file regardless of type, sure. But if you append the checksum to the end of a file of arbitrary type, it may make the file unusable/corrupted when it's read.

Comment: @Adrian the question is not clear, but I would hope if the desire is to checksum, this would be stored in a single manifest file, or a path with say an additional `.md5`  extension.

Comment: @Adrian Can you checksum /dev/random ?

Comment: @Volker sure you can. It would never finish, and even if it did would have no value, but you can execute a checksum algorithm against anything readable.

Comment: @Adrian Yes, and with transfinite Turing machines this could even produce a result!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to add a fingerprint to a file programmatically that works on every filetype?

No. Lots of files are not writable and you cannot add nothing. Even along those which are writable this doesn't work in general (e.g. /dev/null).

Answer (score 1):

Some filesystems support arbitrary metadata. Perhaps it is a good way to add extra info like the checksum.

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/290151/what-does-mounting-a-filesystem-with-user-xattr-do

However, you may lost such information if you move the file to another filesystem.

There is even a go library

https://github.com/davecheney/xattr